# Advice on deploying to live web server via SSH with existing repos on GitHub

Tags: git, github, ssh, deployment

I've been researching improving my workflow and using Git to push changes to my live web server via SSH, instead of just dragging and dropping changed files manually via FTP. I'm a bit confused on what process i should be taking though based on my current situation.

Right now i use Github (Desktop App Mostly) to store and keep track of my projects. But i dont push any changes to a live server from Github/Git, i just pull changes from master branch on whatever computer im using and then when im done i push the changes to github from github desktop and manually drag and drop the changed files to my Bluehost server via FTP.

What I'd like to do is push the changes to my Github origin repo from Github Desktop, and then have it also push the changes to my live bluehost server via SSH. Does this sound like the right approach? And does the fact that i already have existing repos on github matter? Am i able to keep the repos on github? Most guides ive seen start with a new repo on their server. Confused on how it works with an existing repo on Github..

Any resources or guides on how to accomplish this are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Having an existing GitHub repository would matter if you are using GItHub actions (or [GItLab-CI pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/) if you were using GitLab)

Meaning: actions which runs on the remote Git repository hosting server itself.

For instance, the [`ssh-deploy`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ssh-deploy) would allow you to rsync a folder to a deployment server, which would therefore no longer require Git itself. (one less dependency in a runtime production server is good)

Or, if you still want to do your git pull on your deployment server, [`appleboy/ssh-action`](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action) which allows you to ssh and execute any script you want (like one doing a cd to your deployed Git repository, and do a `git pull`)